# Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Речь о сакраментальной фразе "Осторожно(,) двери закрываются". Какой знак препинания должен стоять после "осторожно": тире, двоеточие, восклицательный знак или все-таки запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы я писала эту фразу, то поставила бы восклицательный знак. Двоеточие тоже будет верным: вторая часть указывает на причину того, о чем говорится в первой. Тире не верно. Запятая, в общем, тоже, но на практике используется в бессоюзном предложении, когда причинно-следственные, временные. пояснительные или иные отношения не слишком заметны или их не хотят  замечать...